# Есть ли скрытый ввод пароля в C++ standart

Tags: пароль, c++, ввод

есть ли скрытый скрытый способ ввода пароля в C++ standart

т.е например набиваем в консоли пароль, а вместо букв появляются звездочки или ничего не выводится?

Comment: в стандарте языка? Смеетесь что ли?

Comment: ну я просто подумал если есть в стандарте объект ввода cin то может быть есть аналогичный этому объекту объект например pass

Comment: @DreamChild, ничего смешного, в Python, например, есть стандартный модуль [getpass][1].


  [1]: http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html

Comment: Из top 10 поиска http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread355225.html#post12016346

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) [Hide user input on password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899025/hide-user-input-on-password-prompt)

2) [Capture stdin input without echoing characters to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073418/capture-stdin-input-without-echoing-characters-to-screen)

3) [Read a password from std::cin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/read-a-password-from-stdcin)

Comment: спасибо. но печально. придется передавать данные в систему, безопасности 0

Comment: в какую систему? в операционную?

Comment: да в нее .

Comment: в любом случае оно туда попадает. Если только Вы не избавитесь от операционной системы:)

Comment: да я сточки зрения безопасности на этот вопрос смотрю 

если вызывается системная функция то можно с помощью операционной системы найти или перехватить эти данные в чистом виде зная адрес этой функции которая получает пароль.

а надо сделать так чтоб данные не выходили за область вашей программы (то есть находились в оперативной памяти в зашифрованном виде). тогда узнать пароль невозможно

ps
народная байка 

знают двое - знают все, в нашем случае написанная программа и ОС

ваши три варианта отлично работают но они все не безопасны, это защита от младшего брата если так можно сказать.

Comment: В любом случае программа запускается под операционной системой. C++ не изобретает колеса и использует возможности ос.

Comment: вот это и огорчает. а ответ да правильный я и не оспорил его

Comment: @perfect, если у злоумышленника есть доступ к компьютеру жертвы, то тут уж ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: а с клавиатурой программа будет работать мимо ос?