# Звездочки вместо символов в консоли

Tags: c++, консоль

Проблема заключается в том , что я пишу функцию для ввода пароля и логина , и мне надо скрыть символы пароля , т.е. заменить символы на звездокчки(*);
Windows

Comment: Винда, линукс, или кросс-платформенно?

Comment: Делайте ввод отдельно, вывод отдельно.

Comment: Для винды достаточно функций GetStdHandle + ReadConsoleInput  + WriteFile.

Comment: Сможешь показать как осуществить ???

Comment: Поисковик "с++ ввод пароля" в топ 10-ке есть http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread355225.html#post12016346

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Есть ли скрытый ввод пароля в C++ standart](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232241/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-c-standart)

Comment: @nick_n_a только вот старый ответ - это набор ссылок на англоязычный ресурс, нехорошо.