# Как заменить введённый текст на *

Tags: c++

Первый раз пишу на c++ и решения не нашёл.
Мне нужно что-то по типу скрытия паролей

Вот мой код:

```cpp
string password;
cout << "Введите пароль: ";
cin >> password;
```

И теперь всё что я ввожу выводится в консоль. Мне нужно заменить введённый текст на *
В интернете нашёл только как скрыть текст полностью установив SetConsoleMode на 0

Comment: Пожалуй, проще всего использовать `getch()` из `<conio.h>`/ и при каждом введенном символе самому выводить звездочку...

Comment: Тогда нужно вручную обрабатывать кнопки Backspace, Space, Enter поэтому я хотел что-нибудь готовое если такое существует

Comment: @AlexGlebe ещё раз повторюсь "Тогда нужно вручную обрабатывать кнопки Backspace, Space, Enter" поэтому я хотел что-нибудь готовое если такое существует

Comment: ну тогда такое [Есть ли скрытый ввод пароля в C++ standart](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232241/Есть-ли-скрытый-ввод-пароля-в-c-standart)

Comment: @AlexGlebe Ответы такие-же. Везде getch где нужна ручная проверка на клавиши